# c# read lines and store values in dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net

I want to read a csv file and store the values in a correct way in dictionaries.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"CSV_testdaten.csv"))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string new_line;
        while ((new_line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var values = new_line.Split(",");               
            g.add_vertex(values[0], new Dictionary<string, int>() { { values[1], Int32.Parse(values[2]) } });
        }
    }
}
```

the add_vertex function looks like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> vertices = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();

    public void add_vertex(string name, Dictionary<string, int> edges)
    {
        vertices[name] = edges;
    }
```

The csv file looks like this:

[image]

there are multiple lines with the same values[0] (e.g. values[0] is "0") and instead of overwriting the existing dictionary, it should be added to the dictionary which already exists with values[0] = 0. like this:

```
    g.add_vertex("0", new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "1", 731 } , 
{ "2", 1623 } , { "3" , 1813 } , { "4" , 2286 } , { "5" , 2358 } ,
{ "6" , 1 } , ... });
```

I want to add all values which have the same ID (in the first column of the csv file) to one dictionary with this ID. But I'm not sure how to do this. Can anybody help?

Comment: If your `add_vertex` method (which would be more conventionally called `AddVertex`, by the way - it's a good idea to get into the habit of following naming conventions early) only ever needs to accept a single edge, why not change it to `AddVertex(string name, string edgeName, int edgeValue)`? (I've just guessed at the parameter names - I can't tell what the edges are meant to represent.) Then just check whether the dictionary already contains an entry for that vertex name, and create a new value (also a dictionary) if not. Either way, add the new entry to the dictionary for that vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we have complex data and we want to *query* them, *Linq* can be very helpful:

```
var records = File
  .ReadLines(@"CSV_testdaten.csv")
  .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // to be on the safe side
  .Select(line => line.Split(','))
  .Select(items => new {
     vertex = items[0],
     key    = items[1],  
     value  = int.Parse(items[2])  
   })
  .GroupBy(item => item.vertex)
  .Select(chunk => new {
     vertex = chunk.Key,
     dict   = chunk.ToDictionary(item => item.key, item => item.value)
  });

foreach (var record in records)
  g.add_vertex(record.vertex, record.dict);
```

Comment: this works perfectly for me. thank you! for some reason I had to split the line in the csv on (";") but everything else works great. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
vertices =
    File
        .ReadLines(@"CSV_testdaten.csv")
        .Select(x => x.Split(','))
        .Select(x => new { vertex = x[0], name = x[1], value = int.Parse(x[2]) })
        .GroupBy(x => x.vertex)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToDictionary(y => y.name, y => y.value));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split your code in two parts. First will read csv lines:

```
public static IEnumerable<(string, string, string)> ReadCsvLines()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"CSV_testdaten.csv"))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string newLine;
            while ((newLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var values = newLine.Split(',');

                yield return (values[0], values[1], values[2]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and second will add those lines to dictionary:

```
var result = ReadCsvLines()
    .ToArray()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToDictionary(t => t.Item2, t => int.Parse(t.Item3)));
```

With your input `result` would be:

[image]